# How to get the gradient of the specific output of the neural network to the network parameters

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gradient, bayesian-networks

I am building a Bayesian neural network, and I need to manually calculate the gradient of each neural network output and update the network parameters.

For example, in the following network, how can I get the gradient of neural network output **ag** and **bg** to the neural network parameters **phi**, it's --**∂ag/∂phi** and **∂bg/∂phi**--, and update the parameters respectively.

```
class encoder(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, _l_dim, _hidden_dim, _fg_dim):
    super(encoder, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_nn = nn.Linear(_l_dim, _hidden_dim)
    self.ag_nn = nn.Linear(_hidden_dim, _fg_dim)
    self.bg_nn = nn.Linear(_hidden_dim, _fg_dim)

def forward(self, _lg):
    ag = self.ag_nn(self.hidden_nn(_lg))
    bg = self.bg_nn(self.hidden_nn(_lg))
    return ag, bg
```

Comment: The question looks unclear to me. Are you asking how to implement it? You may like to provide more details about how to compute gradients of bayesian networks.

Comment: If I remember correctly from OP's previous deleted post. OP wants to compute the gradient of the weights for each loss term *separately* to measure their respective contribution in the overall gradient descent.

Comment: When I get ag and bg through forward propagation, I need to calculate ∂ag/∂phi and ∂bg/∂phi respectively to evaluate the contribution of the two parts to the gradient, but ag.backward() does not seem to be able to achieve this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do compute dx/dW, you can use autograd for that.  `torch.autograd.grad(x, W, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x), retain_graph=True)`.  Does that actually accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. torch.autograd.grad seems to be more convenient to "take out" the gradient. In fact, after I get the parameters of ag through the ag_params() method provided by @Ivan, I can calculate the gradient I need through torch.autograd.grad.

Answer (score 0):

##### Problem statement

You are looking to compute the gradients of the parameters corresponding to each loss term. Given a model `f`, parametrized by `θ_ag` and `θ_bg`. These two parameter sets might overlap: that's the case here since you have a shared hidden layer. Then `f(x; θ_ag, θ_bg)` will output a pair of elements `ag` and `bg`. Your loss function is defined as `L = L_ag + L_bg`.

The terms you want to compute are `dL_ag/dθ_ag` and `dL_bg/dθ_bg`, which is different from what you would typically get with a single backward call: which gives `dL/dθ_ag` and `dL/dθ_bg`.

---

##### Implementation

In order to compute those terms, you will require two backward passes, after both of them we will compute the respective terms. Before starting, here are a couple things you need to do:

- It will be useful to make `θ_ag` and `θ_bg` available to us. You can, for example, add those two functions in your model definition:

  ```
  def ag_params(self):
      return [*self.hidden_nn.parameters(), *self.ag_nn.parameters()]

  def bg_params(self):
      return [*self.hidden_nn.parameters(), *self.bg_nn.parameters()]
  ```
- Assuming you have a loss function `loss_fn` which outputs two scalar values `L_ab` and `L_bg`. Here is a mockup for `loss_fn`:

  ```
   def loss_fn(ab, bg):
      return ab.mean(), bg.mean()
  ```
- We will need an optimizer to zero the gradient out, here SGD:

  ```
  optim = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
  ```

---

Then we can start applying the following method:

1. Do an inference to compute `ag`, and `bg` as well as `L_ag`, and `L_bg`:

   ```
   >>> ag, bg = model(x)
   >>> L_ag, L_bg = loss_fn(ag, bg)
   ```
2. Backpropagate once on `L_ag`, while retaining the graph:

   ```
   >>> L_ag.backward(retain_graph=True)
   ```

   At this point, we can collect `dL_ag/dθ_ag` on the parameters contained in `θ_ag`. For example, you could pick the norm of the different parameter gradients using the `ag_params` function:

   ```
   >>> pgrad_ag = torch.stack([p.grad.norm() 
          for p in m.ag_params() if p.grad is not None])
   ```
3. Next we can proceed with a second backpropagation, this time on `L_bg`. But before that, we need to clear the gradients so `dL_ag/dθ_ag` doesn't pollute the next computation:

   ```
   >>> optim.zero_grad()
   ```

   Backpropagation on `L_bg`:

   ```
   >>> L_bg.backward(retain_graph=True)
   ```

   Here again, we collect the gradient norms, *i.e.* the gradient of `dL/dθ_bg`, this time using the `bg_params` function:

   ```
   >>> pgrad_bg = torch.stack([p.grad.norm() 
          for p in m.bg_params() if p.grad is not None])
   ```

---

Now you have `pgrad_ag` and `pgrad_bg` which correspond to the gradient norms of `dL/dθ_bg`, and `dL/dθ_bg` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I can get dL/dθ_ag and dL/dθ_bg. But my actual scene is a little different. I try to bring the gradient directly into the iterative formula of the designed probability graph model for calculation. There is no additional loss function L to process ag and bg, because the subscript of g represents G samples, and I need to get each sample Gradient. In other words, ag and bg will be a vector, and dL/dθ_ag and dL/dθ_b will be a gradient vector. I want to know, can I still use the above method to achieve and take out the gradient vector for operation.

Comment: Can you detail your setup? It would be best if you could edit your question above with the relevant information and a minimal example as you did with `L_ag` and `L_bg`.

Comment: We have designed a probabilistic graph model in which a neural network is used to approximate the parameters `ag` and `bg` of the `Beta distribution`, `g={1,2, ..., G}`. The probability graph model is solved by MLE, and an iterative formula for neural network parameters φ is obtained, `φ_{t+1} = φ_{t} + η▽φ`, where `η` is the learning rate. And the formula obtained by MLE for `▽φ`, `▽φ=▽ag*(∂ag/∂φ)+▽bg*(∂bg/∂φ)`, so in order to update the neural network parameters `φ`, we need to calculate `∂ag/∂φ` And `∂bg/∂φ`. Is it clearer now?